# Simply stack column to existing table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Simple question. Say I have a table with two columns, PersonID and CardID and 10 rows. I have another Table that contains 1 column, Code and 10 rows. I simply want to stack the codes to the other table. Note that is does not matter which person gets which code, they should all just get one.

At the moment I find myself adding rownumbers in both tables and updating were TableA.ID = TableB.ID. But this seems overly complex for such a simple taks.

Any suggestions?

```
TableA
PersonID CardID
1        1
2        2
3        3
4        4
5        5
6        6
7        7
8        8
9        9
10       10

Table B
Code
Random1
Random2
Random3
Random4
Random5
Random6
Random7
Random8
Random9
Random10

Desired Result:
PersonID CardID Code
1        1      Random1
2        2      Random2
3        3      Random3
4        4      Random4
5        5      Random5
6        6      Random6
7        7      Random7
8        8      Random8
9        9      Random9
10       10     Random10
```

Again, code order does not matter. Each person, one code. That's it.

Comment: what do you mean by `stack the codes to the other table` , please show by posting some sample data and expected result

Comment: You really can't tell sql to randomly append 1 extra column to each row ... best way is to go with `rownumbers` there, and it ain't that complex and it is correct

Comment: Does each person need to be allocated a unique code, or can all people be allocated the same code?

Comment: @PeterAbolins each person, 1 unique code. Which code is not important.

Comment: Yeah ROW_NUMBER is about the only thing you can do. As already stated it isn't very complex. And you need some mechanism to be able to join the rows.

Comment: Ok, I should have stated 'relatively complex', compared to the simple task at hand. Obviously it's not complex, it just seems inefficient.

Comment: Well what you are doing here is not really how relational data is designed to be handled. You are saying give me the rows from one table and join them randomly to another table. You just about have to do a cte for each table and then join those two ctes together with a full outer join on the ROW_NUMBER result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need not to append 1 extra column to each row, You can use CTE with RowNum  like :

```
;WITH CTE_Results
AS (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Code) as ID, Code
  from TableB B
  )
  select A.PersonId, A.CardID, CTE_Results.Code  from CTE_Results
  INNER JOIN TableA A ON A.PersonId= CTE_Results.ID
```

Working SQL Fiddle is : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f8f86/9

Result will be like :

```
PersonId    CardID  Code
1   1   Random1
2   2   Random10
3   3   Random2
4   4   Random3
5   5   Random4
6   6   Random5
7   7   Random6
8   8   Random7
9   9   Random8
10  10  Random9
```